# PHP Abraham's TwitterOAuth, Error 32 Could not authenticate you

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

First, I must say I have read many post about this issue but I still can't solve it.

I am using Abraham's TwitterOAuth library in order to send a big quantity of retweets, with this code:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $arrayTokens[0][$i], $arrayTokens[1][$i]);
$connection->post('statuses/retweet/' . $_POST['id']);
```

And it works but only with some users, with others (most of them), I get this:

```
array(1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
      ["message"]=>
      string(26) "Could not authenticate you"
      ["code"]=>
      int(32)
    }
  }
}
```

I have read in twitter developers community too and I tried to add these lines:

```
    $connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
    $connection->ssl_verifypeer = TRUE;
    $connection->content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

...but the same problem occurs.

Every tokens are valid, and I have the last version of the library, so I don't understand what is happening. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [account/verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials) endpoint for each set of tokens you have to make certain that they are valid.

Comment: This returns me the same ["message"]=> string(26) "Could not authenticate you"

Comment: Then the auth tokens must be invalid. Those docs say "Use this method to test if supplied user credentials are valid" so it appears they have either revoked access to the app, or, more likely, you're using the wrong values.

Comment: But the api says "returns a 401 status code and an error message if not." and this doesn't return me a 401 status code

Comment: The problem was that I was using tokens from app B with app A, so they weren't valid